# Как вызвать JNI метод не из UI потока?

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, jni

У меня есть метод вот такой метод

```
void setProfileTime(int iTime, const ProfileType &type)
    {
        JNIEnv *env = GetJniEnv();

        // Put all the JNI values in a structure that is statically initalized on the
        // first call to this method.  This makes it thread safe in the unlikely case
        // of multiple threads calling this method.
        static struct JNIData
        {
            jclass helper_class;
            jmethodID load_image_method;
        }
                jniIds = [env]() -> JNIData {
            constexpr char kHelperClassName[] = "com/my_custom_class/ar/JniInterface";
            constexpr char kLoadImageMethodName[] = "loadImagee";
            constexpr char kLoadImageMethodSignature[] = "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;";

            jclass helper_class = FindClass(kHelperClassName);

            if (helper_class)
            {
                helper_class = static_cast<jclass>(env->NewGlobalRef(helper_class));
                jmethodID load_image_method = env->GetStaticMethodID(
                        helper_class, kLoadImageMethodName, kLoadImageMethodSignature);

                return {helper_class, load_image_method};
            }

            LOGE("my_custom_class::util::Could not find Java helper class %s",
                 kHelperClassName);

            return {};
        }();

        if (!jniIds.helper_class)
        {
            return;
        }

        jstring j_path = env->NewStringUTF(std::to_string(4).c_str());

        jobject image_obj = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(jniIds.helper_class, jniIds.load_image_method, j_path);
    }
```

Я вызываю его из `cpp` когда мне нужно обратиться к `Java` классам

Проблема в том, что когда я вызываю этот метод из одного потока (UI) все работает, когда я вызываю этот метод из другого созданного `cpp` потока, то получаю `NULL` в это строке

```
jclass helper_class = FindClass(kHelperClassName);
```

Не пойму в чем может быть причина...

Кто работал с JNI скажите это номальное поведение?

**EDIT1**

Метод который возвращает `JNIEnv`

```
JNIEnv *GetJniEnv()
{
 JNIEnv *env;
 jint result = g_vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, nullptr);
 return result == JNI_OK ? env : nullptr;
}
```

**EDIT2**

Мой `JNI_OnLoad()` метод

```
jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *)
{
    g_vm = vm;
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

Мой `FindClass()` метод

```
jclass FindClass(const char *classname)
{
    JNIEnv *env = GetJniEnv();
    return env->FindClass(classname);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Из [документации](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#faq:-why-didnt-findclass-find-my-class):

> You can get into trouble if you create a thread yourself (perhaps by
>   calling pthread_create and then attaching it with
>   AttachCurrentThread). Now there are no stack frames from your
>   application. If you call `FindClass` from this thread, the JavaVM will
>   start in the "system" class loader instead of the one associated with
>   your application, so attempts to find app-specific classes will fail.
>
> There are a few ways to work around this:
>
> - Do your `FindClass` lookups once, in [JNI_OnLoad](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#JNJI_OnLoad), and cache the class references for later use. Any `FindClass` calls made as part of
>     executing `JNI_OnLoad` will use the class loader associated with the
>     function that called `System.loadLibrary` (this is a special rule,
>     provided to make library initialization more convenient). If your app
>     code is loading the library, `FindClass` will use the correct class
>     loader.
> - Pass an instance of the class into the functions that need it, by declaring your native method to take a Class argument and then passing
>     Foo.class in.
> - Cache a reference to the ClassLoader object somewhere handy, and issue loadClass calls directly. This requires some effort.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko обновил ответ.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос свой `JNI_OnLoad()` и насколько я понимаю это соотсетствует первому пункту в вашем ответе, верно? То есть проблема не в этом... или я что то не так понял?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko вам надо в `JNI_onLoad` загрузить все необходимые классы и сохранить их где-нибудь, чтобы при `setProfileTime` можно было не вызывать `FindClass`.